# Display parent attirbute with child fields to a datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datagridview, dataset

Net folks,

The xml example below when fed to a dataset would yield 2 tables. table 1 would contain the parent names, and table 2 would contain all the childfields and the childId. How do I display in a datagridview the parent name and the childfields?

```
<root>
    <parent name="parent1">
        <child id="1">
            <childfield1>child1</childfield1>
        </child>
        <child id="2">
            <childfield1>chil2</childfield1>
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent name="parent2">
        <child id="1">
            <childfield1>child1</childfield1>
        </child>
        <child id="2">
            <childfield1>child2</childfield1>
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

Sample output:

```
Parentname childfield1 childid
parent1    child1      1
parent1    child2      2
parent2    child1      1
parent2    child2      2
```

Original code:

```
DataSet ds = New DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("../xmldata.xml");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
```

Comment: It all depends on XML structure which you need. Can they be more or less levels of nesting? Can there be other tag names? For example, for this XML you can use XPath to extract all nodes which have depth equal to 3. Then, you can just output `node.ParentNode.ParentNode.Name`, `node.ParentNode.Name` and `node.Name`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But how do you load that in a datagridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this.

```
 var listOfRecord = (from parent in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  join chile in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() on parent.Field<int>("parent_id") equals chile.Field<int>("parent_id")
                  select new
                  {
                      ParentName = parent.Field<string>("name"),
                      ChildField = chile.Field<string>("childfield1"),
                      ChildId = chile.Field<string>("id"),
                  }).ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = listOfRecord;
```

Comment: Ow wow, what if the child fields are dynamic, is there a way to select them all?